# use FAB in android - support libraries 23.2.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button

I can use FAB in support libraries 23.1.1  perfectly , when I put it in XML it appear without any problem . but when I use android - support libraries 23.2.1 or higher , and try to use FAB and put in XML , it doesn't appear as FAB , just a blank  rectangle .please how can I  use FAB in these  libraries ?   I tried to rebuild the project but nothing happened .
 this is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maysara.maysara_.com.textonwallpaper"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you add your XML layout, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Android SDK Manager and see if there are any updates available to following:

- Android SDK Build Tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Android Support Library

update, rebuild and see if it solves the problem.